# Como importar um arquivo inteiro (javascript) com WebPack?

Tags: javascript, webpack

Eu comecei estudar WebPack agora, consegui usa-lo normalmente, porém, quando eu quero importar algo de outro arquivo eu preciso dar:

```
import {abc} from './my-file.js';
```

e no arquivo que foi importado:

```
export function abc() {
    console.log('MODULO 1 do projeto');
}
```

Até ai OK. Porém, como eu importo o arquivo inteiro? Sem necessidade de especificar apenas a função ou variável que eu quero? Quero importar o arquivo e poder usar tudo o que há nele (variáveis, funções e etc...).

Eu tentei dar apenas:

```
import './my-file.js';
```

Entretanto, ele não reconhece nada que há dentro deste arquivo, ele compila normalmente, porém ocorre erro ao invocar funções (função não foi definida).

Então, existe como eu importar o arquivo inteiro?

Answer (score 1):

Consegui resolver usando Laravel Mix, por algum acaso se alguém tiver a mesma dúvida, pesquise sobre Laravel Mix.

Pequeno curso sobre laravel-mix feito pelo seu próprio criador: https://laracasts.com/series/learn-laravel-mix/

Laravel Mix é uma parte do framework php Laravel, entretanto, é possível usar apenas o Laravel Mix para 'empacotar' de uma forma extremamente simples e fácil os arquivos sass, less, js e etc... sem usar todo o framework Laravel

Answer (score 0):

Olá! Já faz um bom tempo desde a pergunta, mas tive a mesma duvida e na tentativa e erro consegui da seguinte forma:

```
import * as utils from './uteis.js'
```